# Selenium IDE passing external javascript files

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I need to trigger my Selenium IDE test in windows command prompt but I have multiple selenium core extension files and I need to know if it is possible to pass them in the following command

Selenium Ide firefox plugin:

I need to pass all three js files in my argument

[image]

This is what i got so far:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar --userExtensions user-extensions.js  -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://localhost" "C:\mytestsuite\mytestsuite.html" "C:\mytestsuite\results.html
```

Comment: I've never tried this, I've only done it with the single user-extensions.js file. Have you tried passing it comma separated values?

Comment: @DMart nope I havent tried comma separating them. I tried replacing the user-extension.js file with for example calc.js and it complained about that the file passing must be called user-extension.js.

Comment: @Dmart I found some information about two commands that might work: userExtensions <file>
indicates a JavaScript file that will be loaded into selenium -userJsInjection <file>
Specifies a JavaScript file which will then be injected into all page

Comment: Honestly I didn't think you could do more than 1 file.
attached new ansewer

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Running_IDE_scripts_with_Selenium_RC

> Create a file that contains all user extensions required by the tests.
>   Name the file user-extensions.js and save in the directory containing
>   selenium-server.jar.  If the tests require only one user extension the
>   user extension file may be copied and renamed.  If multiple user
>   extensions are needed copy/append them into one file.  If the sequence
>   in which they are listed is significant in the Selenium Core
>   Extensions option in IDE, they must appear the same sequence in the
>   user-extensions.js file.